# How to improve People Occlusion in ARKit 3.0

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

We are working on a demo app using people's occlusion in ARKit. Because we want to add videos in the final scene, we use `SCNPlane`s to render the video using a `SCNBillboardConstraint` to ensure they are facing the right way. These videos are also partially transparent, using a custom shader on the `SCNMaterial` we apply (thus playing 2 videos at once).

Now we have some issues where the people's occlusion is very iffy (see image). The video we are using to test is a woman with dark pants and a skirt (if you were wondering what the black is in the image).

The issues we have are that the occlusion does not always line up with the person (as visible in the picture), and that someone's hair is not always correctly detected.

Now our question is what causes these issues? And how can we improve the problems until they look like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkS-VqAss4s)? We are currently exploring if the issues are because we are using a plane, but simply using a `SCNBox` does not fix the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Updated: March 06, 2023**.

### New Depth API

You can improve a quality of `People Occlusion` and `Object Occlusion` features in ARKit 3.5 / 6.0 thanks to a new ***Depth API*** with high-quality ZDepth channel that can be rendered at 60 fps. However, to acquire it, you need an iPhone or iPad with a LiDAR scanner. In ARKit 3.0 you can't improve `People Occlusion` feature unless you use Metal or MetalKit (so, it's not easy).

***Tip***: Consider that **RealityKit** and **AR QuickLook** frameworks support `People Occlusion` as well.

### Why does this issue happen when you use People Occlusion?

It's due to the nature of depth data. We all know that a rendered final image of 3D scene can contain 5 main channels for digital compositing – `Red`, `Green`, `Blue`, `Alpha`, and `ZDepth`.

[image]

There are, of course, other useful render passes (also known as AOVs) for compositing:  `Normals`, `MotionVectors`, `PointPosition`, `UVs`, `Disparity`,  etc. But in this post we're interested only in two main render sets – `RGBA` and `ZDepth`.

### ZDepth channel has three serious drawbacks in ARKit 3.0

---

#### Problem 1. Aliasing and Anti-aliasing of ZDepth

Rendering ZDepth channel in any High-End software (like Nuke, Fusion, Maya or Houdini), by default results in ***jagged edges*** or so called aliased edges. There's no exception for game engines – SceneKit, RealityKit, Unity, Unreal, or Stingray have this issue too.

Of course, you could say that before rendering we must turn on a feature called `Anti-aliasing`. And, yes, it works fine for almost all the channels, but not for ZDepth. The problem of ZDepth is – borderline pixels of every foreground object (especially if it's transparent) are "transitioned" into background object, if `anti-aliased`. In other words, pixels of FG and BG are mixed on a margin of FG object.

Frankly speaking, today there's only one working solution in professional compositing industry for fixing depth issues – Nuke compositors use [Deep channels](https://learn.foundry.com/nuke/content/comp_environment/deep/deep_compositing.html) instead of a `ZDepth`. But no one game engine supports it because `Deep` channel is dauntingly huge. So deep channel comp is neither for game engines, nor for ARKit / RealityKit. Alas!

[image]

#### Problem 2. Resolution of ZDepth

Regular `ZDepth` channel must be rendered in `32-bit`, even if `RGB` and `Alpha` channels are both `8-bit` only. Depth-data's 32-bit files are a heavy burden for CPU and GPU. ARKit often merges several layers in viewport. For example, compositing of real-world foreground character over virtual model and over real-world background character. Don't you think it's too much for your device, even if these layers are composited at [viewport resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60731258/arkit-viewport-size-vs-real-screen-resolution/60788960#60788960) instead of real screen rez? However, rendering `ZDepth` channel in `16-bit` or `8-bit` compresses the depth of your real scene, lowering the quality of compositing.

To lessen a burden on CPU and GPU and to save battery life, Apple engineers decided to use a scaled-down ZDepth image at capture stage and then scale-up a rendered ZDepth image up to a Viewport Resolution and **Stencil** it using Alpha channel (a.k.a. segmentation) and then fix ZDepth channel's edges using **Dilate** compositing operation. Thus, this led us to such nasty artefacts that we can see at your picture (some sort of "trail").

[image]

[image]

Please, look at **Presentation Slides pdf** of `Bringing People into AR` [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/607).

#### Problem 3. Frame rate of ZDepth

Third problem stems from FPS. ARKit and RealityKit work at `60 fps`. Scaling down ZDepth image resolution doesn't lessen a processing. So, the next logical step for ARKit 3.0's engineers was – to lower a ZDepth's frame rate to `15 fps`. However, the latest versions of ARKit and RealityKit render ZDepth channel at 60 fps, what considerably improves a quality of People Occlusion and Objects Occlusion. But in ARKit 3.0 this exposed artifacts (some kind of "drop frame" for ZDepth channel which results in "trail" effect).

You can't change the quality of a resulted composited image when you use this type property:

```
static var personSegmentationWithDepth: ARConfiguration.FrameSemantics { get }
```

because it's a gettable property and there's no settings for ZDepth quality in ARKit 3.0.

And, of course, if you want to increase a frame rate of ZDepth channel in ARKit 3.0 you should implement a `frame interpolation technique` found in digital compositing (where in-between frames are computer-generated ones).

[image]

But this frame interpolation technique is CPU intensive, because we need to generate 45 additional 32-bit ZDepth-frames per every second (45 interpolated + 15 real = 60 frames per second).

I believe that someone might improve ZDepth compositing features in ARKit 3.0 using Metal but it's a real challenge for developers. Look at [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/effecting_people_occlusion_in_custom_renderers) of `People Occlusion in Custom Renderers`.

### ARKit 6.0 and LiDAR scanner support

In ARKit 3.5....6.0 there's a support for LiDAR (`Light Detection And Ranging` scanner). LiDAR scanner improves the quality of People Occlusion feature, because the quality of ZDepth channel is higher, even if you're not physically moving when you're tracking a surrounding environment. LiDAR system can also help you map walls, ceiling, floor and furniture to quickly get a virtual mesh for real-world surfaces to dynamically interact with, or simply locate 3d objects on them (even partially occluded virtual objects). Gadgets having LiDAR can achieve matchless accuracy retrieving real-world surfaces' locations. By considering the mesh, ray-casts can intersect with nonplanar surfaces or surfaces with no-features-at-all, such as white walls or barely-lit walls.

To activate `sceneReconstruction` option use the following code:

```
let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    
arView.automaticallyConfigureSession = false

let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

config.sceneReconstruction = .meshWithClassification

arView.debugOptions.insert([.showSceneUnderstanding, .showAnchorGeometry])

arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options.insert([.occlusion,
                                                      .collision,
                                                      .physics])
arView.session.run(config)
```

[image]

But before using `sceneReconstruction` instance property in your code you need to check whether device has a LiDAR Scanner or not. You can do it in `AppDelegate.swift` file:

```
import ARKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
                       didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        guard ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.supportsSceneReconstruction(.meshWithClassification) 
        else {
            fatalError("Scene reconstruction requires a device with a LiDAR Scanner.")
        }            
        return true
    }
}
```

### RealityKit 2.0

When using RealityKit 2.0 app on iPhone Pro or iPad Pro with LiDAR you have several occlusion options – the same options are available in ARKit 6.0 – an improved `People Occlusion`, `Object Occlusion` (furniture or walls for instance) and `Face Occlusion`. To turn on occlusion in RealityKit 2.0 use the following code:

```
arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options.insert(.occlusion)
```

Comment: I wasn't really expecting an answer that was more geared towards Apple how they could improve it, but I guess your points are valid. We'll just have to wait a bit until they apply some of your suggestions (or until someone who knows Metal and rendering pipelines creates the Metal program to properly do people occlusion)

Comment: The paper you link indicates that deep images *do not* anti-alias depth information. In particular, your second figure, which seems to be taken from the paper, is misquoted. In the paper, the both sides of the figure represent depth channels, however the left side demonstrates why it doesn't make sense to anti-alias a depth channel.