# What are black pixels in ARKit Depth Map pixel buffer?

Tags: objective-c, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, avdepthdata

When taking a depth pixel buffer from ARKit session like:

```
CVPixelBufferRef depthDataMap = frame.capturedDepthData.depthDataMap;
```

many pixels are in black. What do they represent? Why are they black? This doesn't reflect the real depth of the real world.
How to interpret this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## It's some sort of "trail" artifact.

Those black pixels in a Depth channel are digital artifacts. The appearance of this black outline became possible due to the fact that the depth data is captured at a frequency of 15 fps (at every fourth frame), in contrast to the RGB image which is captured at a frequency of 60 fps. Also, a Depth channel image is of a low quality (low-res). Thus, if the subject quickly or abruptly moves its head at the time of AR session running, when every three out of four depth frames contain a completely black background – this leads to a situation when RGBA and Depth data don't match each other, so we get these nasty digital artifacts.

Look at a picture in a post **How to improve People Occlusion in ARKit 3.0** (click on a link below).

> If you need an additional info about a depth map and its *trailing effect*, please read **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58269394/how-to-improve-people-occlusion-in-arkit-3-0/58326062#58326062)**.

Answer (score 0):

This means no depth data for this pixel (depth = 0)