# ARKit – Viewport Size vs Real Screen Resolution

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

I am writing an ARKit app that uses ARSCNView `hitTest` function. Also the app sends captured images to the server for some analysis.

I notices when I do:

```
let viewportSize = sceneView.snapshot().size
let viewSize = sceneView.bounds.size
```

then the first one is twice as large as the second one.

The questions are:

- 1.Why there is a difference?
- 2.What "size" (e.g. coordinates) is used in hitTest?

Comment: viewportSize == 750 x 1334, viewSize == 375 x 667. The model is iPhone 7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Why there is a difference?

**Let's explore some important display characteristics of your iPhone 7**:

- **a resolution of 750 (W) x 1,334 (H) pixels** (16 : 9)
- **viewport rez of 375 (W) x 667 (H) pixels** (16 : 9)

Because mobile devices with the same screen size can have very different resolutions, developers often use **`viewports`** when they are creating 3D scenes or mobile friendly webpages. **In VR and AR fields: the lower resolution is – the quicker a renderer is, and CPU/GPU burden is considerably less**. The idea of creating viewports is mainly used for mobile devices. **In macOS `Screen Resolution` and `Viewport Resolution` are identical**.

[image]

In iPhone, as well as in other mobile devices, **`Viewport`** is a scaled down version (usually 2 or 3 times smaller in each axis) of resolution that allows 3D scenes viewports or websites to be viewed more consistently across different devices and (very important!) **with less energy's consumption**. Viewports are often more standardized and smaller than resolution sizes.

Snapshots almost always reflect a **real screen resolutions**:

```
let screenSize = sceneView.snapshot().size

/*   750 x 1,334    */
/*   iPhone 7 rez   */
```

SceneView size often reflects a **standardized screen resolution** (4 times smaller than specs rez):

```
let viewportSize = sceneView.bounds.size 

/*   375 x 667     */
/*   ViewPort rez  */
```

Viewport Rez (1/4) to Screen Rez aspect ratio in iPhone 7:

Schematic depiction!

[image]

Viewport size and its real layout in mobile device:

Real depiction!

[image]

Additional reference: **`Phone X`** has a ViewPort resolution ***nine times*** smaller (**375 x 812**) than screen resolution (**1125 x 2436**).

### What coordinates are used in Hit-Testing?

**In Hit-Testing and Ray-Casting coordinates of ViewPort are used**.

Let's make 3 taps using hit-testing method – first tap in a Upper Left corner (near `x=0` and `y=0`), second tap in center of the screen and third tap in a Lower Right Corner (near `x=667` and `y=375`):

```
let point: CGPoint = gestureRecognize.location(in: sceneView)

print(point)
```

[image]

Coordinates of iPhone 7 Viewport is printed in a console:

[image]

```
Quod Erat Demonstrandum!
```

Comment: I think this is the most detailed answer I'v ever seen on the site! Thank you!