# What is the real Focal Length of the camera used in RealityKit?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

I am doing this Augmented Reality project starting from Xcode's default AR project.

I need to know the focal length of the camera used by ARKit.

[This page](https://www.nikonusa.com/en/learn-and-explore/a/tips-and-techniques/understanding-focal-length.html) defines Focal Length well:

> Focal length, usually represented in millimeters (mm), is the basic
> description of a photographic lens. It is not a measurement of the
> actual length of a lens, but a calculation of an optical distance from
> the point where light rays converge to form a sharp image of an object
> to the digital sensor or 35mm film at the focal plane in the camera.
> The focal length of a lens is determined when the lens is focused at
> infinity.

Said that, Apple offers this camera matrix called intrinsics, defined as

[image]

According to Apple,

> The values fx and fy are the pixel focal length, and are identical for
> square pixels. The values ox and oy are the offsets of the principal
> point from the top-left corner of the image frame. All values are
> expressed in pixels.

I am getting the same number for `fx` and `fy`, that is `1515.481`.

To obtain the real focal length in millimeters,

1. [This page](https://support.geocue.com/converting-focal-length-from-pixels-to-millimeters-to-use-in-bentley-context-capture/) says I need to use this formula: `F(mm) = F(pixels) * SensorWidth(mm) / ImageWidth (pixel)` but I don't have the sensor dimensions.
2. [this other page](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/86347) says `FC = fx/sx = fy/sy`, where `sx` and `sy` are the image dimensions width and height, what I suppose will give me two numbers, because `fx` = `fy`... and this is back to square zero.

On iPhone 11, ARCamera captures a frame with the following dimensions: 1920x1440, at least this number is reported by the property `camera.imageResolution`.

In the name of mental sanity, is there a way to get the focal length of `ARCamera` used by `RealityKit`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ARKit and RealityKit do definitely have identical values of `focal length` parameter. That's because these two frameworks are supposed to work together. And although there's no `focal length` instance property for `ARView` at the moment, you can easily print in Console a [focal length](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scncamera/2867556-focallength) for `ARSCNView` or `SCNView`.

```
@IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!

sceneView.pointOfView?.camera?.focalLength
```

However, take into account that ARKit, RealityKit and SceneKit frameworks don't use a ***screen resolution***, they rather use a [viewport size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60731258/arkit-viewport-size-vs-real-screen-resolution/60788960#60788960). A magnification factor for iPhones' viewports is usually `1/2` or `1/3`.

### Intrinsic Camera Matrix

[image]

As you said in ARKit there's a 3x3 camera matrix allowing you convert between the 2D camera plane and 3D world coordinate space.

```
var intrinsics: simd_float3x3 { get }
```

Using this matrix you can print 4 important parameters: `fx`, `fy`, `ox` and `oy`. Let's print them all:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
                    
    print(" Focal Length: \(self.sceneView.pointOfView?.camera?.focalLength)")
    print("Sensor Height: \(self.sceneView.pointOfView?.camera?.sensorHeight)")
    // SENSOR HEIGHT IN mm
                    
    let frame = self.sceneView.session.currentFrame

    // INTRINSICS MATRIX
    print("Intrinsics fx: \(frame?.camera.intrinsics.columns.0.x)")
    print("Intrinsics fy: \(frame?.camera.intrinsics.columns.1.y)")
    print("Intrinsics ox: \(frame?.camera.intrinsics.columns.2.x)")
    print("Intrinsics oy: \(frame?.camera.intrinsics.columns.2.y)")
}
```

For `iPhone X` the following values are printed:

[image]

When you apply your formulas you'll get a implausible result (read on to find out why).

### About Wide-Angle Lens and OIS

> The iPhone X has two rear camera sensors, and both those modules are equipped with an ***optical image stabilizer*** (*OIS*). ***The wide-angle lens offers a 28-millimeter focal length*** and an aperture of `f/1.8`, while the telephoto lens is 56 millimeters and `f/2.4`.

ARKit and RealityKit use a wide-angle lens rear module. In iPhone X case it's a 28-mm lens. But what about printed value `focal length = 20.78 mm`, huh? I believe that the discrepancy between the value of `28 mm` and `20.78 mm` is due to the fact that video stabilization eats up about 25% of the total image area. This is done in order to eventually get a focal length's value of `28 mm` for final image.

[image]

Red frame is a cropping margin at stabilisation stage.

### Conclusion

***This is my own conclusion. I didn't find any reference materials on that subject, so do not judge me strictly if my opinion is wrong (I admit it may be)***.

We all know a fact that camera shake is magnified with an increase in focal length. So, the lower value of focal length is, the less camera shake is. It's very important for non-jittering high-quality world tracking in AR app. Also, I firmly believe that Optical Image Stabilisers work much better with lower values of focal length. Hence, it's not a surprise that ARKit engineers have chosen a lower value of `focal length` for AR experience (capturing a wider image area), and then after stabilization, we get a modified version of the image, like it has `focal length = 28 mm`.

So, in my humble opinion, it makes no sense to calculate a REAL `focal length` for RealityKit and ARKit 'cause there is a "FAKE" `focal length` already implemented by Apple engineers for a robust AR experience.

Comment: Hello @Duck, were you able to print the parameters? I tried "@IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!" "sceneView.pointOfView?.camera?.focalLength" but got an error "Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';' "