# ARCore – How to place a Real World object in front of a 3d model?

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, arkit, arcore

I have created an Android AR app using `ARCore Sceneform` plugin. I am able to place 3D models on the highlighted plane. But even if I'm placing a real object in front of the camera (or just waving my hands in front of the camera) it is visible only behind the 3d object.

How can I place real-world objects in front of the 3D objects in Android?

Can we use any other plugin to achieve this?

Comment: Please remove the tag "Java 3D" as you don't use the Java 3D API

Answer (score 2):

### ARCore 1.18

ARCore 1.18 now does support `Occlusion` feature via brand-new Depth API. Check [a list of Depth API supported devices](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices) to find out whether your Android smartphone supports Occlusion capabilities or not.

[image]

Google documentation says about Depth API the following:

> The Depth API uses a depth-from-motion algorithm to create depth maps, which you can obtain using `acquireDepthImage()` method. This algorithm takes multiple device images from different angles and compares them to estimate the distance to every pixel as a user moves their phone. If the device has an active depth sensor, such as a time-of-flight sensor (or ToF sensor), that data is automatically included in the processed depth. This enhances the existing depth map and enables depth even when the camera is not moving. It also provides better depth on surfaces with few or no features, such as white walls, or in dynamic scenes with moving people or objects.

### ARCore 1.17

But you can't do any `Object Occlusion` ops in previous ARCore 1.17. It doesn't support Depth channel compositing and Depth channel ops, except camera defocus feature. So all virtual models you use in your AR app is just placed over a real world video using [Over](https://learn.foundry.com/nuke/8.0/content/user_guide/merging/merge_operations.html) compositing operation with the following formula:

### Argb * Aa + Brgb * (1.0 – Aa)

```
//  where Argb is RGB of a foreground image
//  Aa is Alpha channel of a foreground image
//  Brgb is RGB of a background video
//  and 1.0 is a normalised value (in range 0.0...1.0)

//  (Argb * Aa) is a premultiplied RGBA image
//  (1.0 – Aa) is an inversion of a foreground alpha
```

However, you can get an [Occlusion Management](https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/samples) feature (Virtual Buttons sample) if you use `PTC Vuforia 9.0` in Unity for Android devices. Or if you use ARKit 3.5 or ARKit 4.0 for iOS devices. ARKit 4.0 gives you the widest set of toolkits for working with Depth channel, including new **`Depth API`**. There are [People Occlusion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/occluding_virtual_content_with_people), Face Occlusion and [Object Occlusion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/world_tracking/visualizing_and_interacting_with_a_reconstructed_scene) features.

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58269394/how-to-improve-people-occlusion-in-arkit-3-0/58326062#58326062) you can read about main principles of `Occlusion` in ARKit.

Comment: Thanks. I have created Vuforia developer account. But I cannot login for downloading the SDK. It prompts error saying that entered credentials does not match with stored data. But I have entered correct credentials only.

Comment: How can I get the ARCore 1.18?

Comment: At the moment there's the actual version ARCore 1.20. But you can download any current and previous versions via GitHub: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/releases